# Data from Optitrack is not getting streamed properly to vrpn_client_ros

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, optitrack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm currently using optitrack motive 1.10.1 version for tracking 3 UAVs. i'm using vrpn streaming to stream the data. im connecting the host pc (on which motive is running) to router using lan and connecting the pc running ros to the router's wifi. while im running the sample.launch in vrpn_client_ros package, im getting data slowly at times and quick at times. i couldn't figure out if this is due to pc issue or router issue or motive issue. i would like to know what changes in code needs to be made so that if data/packet doesn't come for any instant then that instant could be displayed. so that i could know the trend of data getting lost

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337889/data-from-optitrack-is-not-getting-streamed-properly-to-vrpn_client_ros/) by [haneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/46796/haneesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First thing to try is to connect everything using cables. Getting data in bursts ("slowly at times and quick at times") seems to point to networking issues. Take out the wireless segment and see whether that improves things.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [haneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/46796/haneesh/) on 2019-11-19**:
@gvdhoorn , thanks .That worked out well